# how to get document that contain more than collection in xslt?

Tags: xslt, schema, xquery, marklogic

```
let $stylesheet := "abc.xsl"
let $params := map:map()
let $_ := map:put ($params,"col1","abc")
return
xdmp:xslt-invoke(
            $stylesheet, (), $params,
            <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
                 <template>a:schema</template>
           
            </options>)
```

**abc.xsl**

```
<xsl:template name="a:schema">
          <xsl:param name="collection-uri" as="xs:string" select="$col1"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="collection($collection-uri)"/>
       </xsl:template>
```

In this currently ,we are taking all the document ,which is coming in collection "abc".
But I want to add more than one collection in $param map, so that the document which contain ,both collection "abc" and "def"  will comes
for example :

```
 | Document| collection
|:---------|:----------:|
| Doc1     | abc, def   |
| Doc2     | abc        |
| Doc3     | abc, def   |
```

it will pick Doc1 and Doc3

Comment: Saxon documentation on collection: https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/sourcedocs/collections.html

See here an example on how to use collection-function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6138562/3710053

Comment: It may be better to use "|" rather than "," to ensure de-duplication of documents present in both collections (but again, I don't know MarkLogic).

Answer (score 2):

[`collection()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/fn:collection) accepts a sequence of `xs:string`, but would return any of the documents in either of the collections specified.

If you want only the docs that are in all of the collections specified, you could use `cts:search()` with a sequence of `cts:collection-query()` inside of a `cts:and-query()`.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:param name="collection-uri" as="xs:string*" select="$col1"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="cts:search(doc(), cts:and-query(( $collection-uri ! cts:collection-query(.) )))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Enable the `1.0-ml` dialect, so that you can use the `cts` built-in functions by adding the following attribute to your `xsl:stylesheet` element:

```
xdmp:dialect="1.0-ml"
```

The `$collection-uri` param is declared as `xs:string`, so it will only have one string value. You could change that to be a sequence of strings with either `*` or `+` quantifier:

```
<xsl:param name="collection-uri" as="xs:string*" select="$col1"/>
```

and then set the collections on the `$col1` param:

```
let $_ := map:put ($params,"col1", ('abc', 'def'))
```

Comment: Hi , please check the updated question,I want those document which contains both collection (abc and def) as using fn:collection(("abc","def")) , those  document will also come that contains either abc or def collection.